# Filter queryset by year between two date fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a start_date and an end_date fields in my model. The user shall be able to filter records by selecting a year value, so that records that span over multiple years should be shown if the year selected is included.

For example:
Selected year: 2019

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-03-12 | 2021-09-03 |
| 2019-12-12 | 2020-06-05 |

I can do this query by raw SQL like that:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE '2019' BETWEEN YEAR(`start_date`) AND YEAR(`end_date`);
```

How can I do this using Django ORM and avoid raw SQL queries? Because I am already using the ORM in multiple filters and only remaining this bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(
    start_date__year__lte=2019, 
    end_date__year__gte=2019,
)
```

Comment: LOL, I don't know why my mind stopped there. Thank you!